# Why is this call stack so weird?

Tags: java, android, callstack

Today I was debugging my android app and it crashes. Here is the call stack:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8822
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:246)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3860)
        at com.whackanandroid.GameActivity.gameOver(GameActivity.java:68)
        at com.whackanandroid.Game$1.onCountDownFinished(Game.java:79)
        at com.whackanandroid.CountDown$1.run(CountDown.java:23)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Then I clicked on the line number links (TextView.java:3860) and it took me to a line of javadoc comment. I was really confused. Comments *never* get executed. That can't be wrong. This is strange.

Here is my code:

```
public void gameOver () {
    tvScore.setText (Integer.toString (Game.getInstance ().getScore ()));
    tvHighscore.setText (Game.getInstance ().getHighscore ());
    tvScoreText.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    tvScore.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this, R.anim.cover_fade_in);
    anim.setAnimationListener (new Animation.AnimationListener () {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            GameActivity.this.cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            GameActivity.this.cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
            Game.InitializeGame (GameActivity.this);
            cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    cover.startAnimation (anim);
}
```

The line `tvHighscore.setText (Game.getInstance ().getHighscore ());` refers to the line in the call stack: `at com.whackanandroid.GameActivity.gameOver(GameActivity.java:68)`. I think it might be because tvHighscore's parent view, a `LinearLayout` is `GONE`. Does this matter? Or did I do anything else wrong?

If you need to see more code, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Different version of current source and source when it was compiled - normally.

Comment: Android is trying to find resource with int value tvHighscore.setText (Game.getInstance ().getHighscore ());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or did I do anything else wrong?

Yes. You called `setText(int)`, with a value that is not a string resource ID. Change:

```
tvHighscore.setText (Game.getInstance ().getHighscore ());
```

to:

```
tvHighscore.setText(Integer.toString(Game.getInstance().getHighscore()));
```

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is pulled in as a dependency and you are debugging that then the lines are from the class file that is created by the complier and not java class it self you have to go my the method name and other information. You cannot always rely on the line number.

Another reason can be different version of current source that you are using to see line number and jar that is pulled in is of different version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `setText` with an integer parameter, this means a resource id.

To solve your problem you could do this:

```
tvHighscore.setText(""+Game.getInstance().getHighscore());
```

Comment: there is no need to concatenate strings here, AS best advice is to wrap with String.valueOf()